# AlpineJS inline function and Laravel @json

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I have a problem passing a PHP variable to a variable inside an alpine variable or function. Here is a simple example.

```html
@php
$test = "Hello World's testing";
@endphp

<div x-data="{
    message: @json($test)
}">

<span x-text="message"></span>
</div>
```

The problem comes from the fact that x-data is using the double-quote to wrap the encoded data. I know I could "externalize" the x-data, but I really need it to be inline.

I have a basic workaround (using backticks) for example, but I wanted to know if there is a better way to do this.

**EDIT**
The example is using a string... but the PHP variable can be a boolean or even an array. That's why I'm using `@json`.

Answer (score 2):

I' d use Template Strings.. Easy to read, no need to escape multiple quotes.

```
<div>
    @php
    $test = "Hello World's testing";
    @endphp

    <div x-data="{
        message: `{{ $test }}`
    }">
        <span x-text="message"></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's the way I was thinking to do it... and it works perfectly for a string. The main problem is what is happening if the variable `$test` is a boolean or an array. That's why I was using `@json`. I'm editing the main question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Will this not work?:

```
@php
$test = "Hello World's testing";
@endphp

<div x-data="{
    message: {{ json_encode($test) }}
}">

<span x-text="message"></span>
</div>
```